# Data Preparation Advanced Pandas Melt Multiple Column Sets. Merge some Columns to make them one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

I have a dataset like:

| Mileage | Operator 1 | 16 Seater | 29-seater | Operator 2 | 16-seater.1 | 29-seater.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | BusRus | £199 | £299 | Wheels | £190 | £290 |

I want it in the following format to build a price prediction model with Operator and Seats as Features

| Mileage | Operator | Seats | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | BusRus | 16 Seater | £199 |
| 80 | BusRus | 29 Seater | £299 |
| 80 | Wheels | 16 Seater | £190 |
| 80 | Wheels | 29 Seater | £290 |

Removed columns for simplicity

Data Set Has Nulls as sometimes you only get quotes for a particular seater vehicle or less Operators

I've tried the following code aswell:

```
import pandas as pd

# create the original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Mileage': [80],
    'Operator 1': ['BusRus'],
    '16-Seater': ['£199'],
    '29-Seater': ['£299'],
    'Operator 2': ['Wheels'],
    '16-Seater.1': ['£190'],
    '29-Seater.1': ['£290']
})

# melt the dataframe from wide to long format
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Mileage', 'Operator 1', 'Operator 2'],
                  var_name='Seats', value_name='Price')

# split the 'Seats' column into two columns - one for the number of seats and one for the type of vehicle
df_melt[['NumSeats', 'VehicleType']] = df_melt['Seats'].str.split('-', expand=True)

# determine the correct operator for each row based on which 'Seats' column the price belongs to
df_melt['Operator'] = df_melt.apply(lambda x: x['Operator 1'] if '1' in x['Seats'] else x['Operator 2'], axis=1)

# drop the original 'Seats' column and rename the remaining columns
df_melt = df_melt.drop('Seats', axis=1).rename(columns={'Operator 1': 'Dummy1', 'Operator 2': 'Dummy2'})

# drop the 'Dummy1' and 'Dummy2' columns and reorder the columns
df_melt = df_melt.drop(['Dummy1', 'Dummy2'], axis=1)[['Mileage', 'Operator', 'NumSeats', 'Price']]

# output the final dataframe
print(df_melt)
```

This gets me close to what I need but the Operators are incorrect

| index | Mileage | Operator | NumSeats | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 80 | BusRus | 16 | £199 |
| 1 | 80 | Wheels | 29 | £299 |
| 2 | 80 | BusRus | 16 | £190 |
| 3 | 80 | BusRus | 29 | £290 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to reorder the columns before flipping with a combination of stack and melt:

```py
temp = df.set_index('Mileage')
regex = r"(?P<num1>\d+)\.(?P<num2>\d)(?P<text>-Seater).*"
repl = lambda g: f"{g['num2']}_{g['num1']}{g['text']}"
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.replace(regex, repl, regex=True)
temp.columns = ["_".join(ent.split()[::-1]) 
               if ent.startswith('Operator') 
               else ent 
               for ent in temp]
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
(temp
.stack(level=0)
.melt(id_vars='Operator', value_name = 'Price', var_name = 'Seats')
)

  Operator      Seats Price
0   BusRus  16-Seater  £199
1   Wheels  16-Seater  £190
2     Taxi  16-Seater  £200
3   BusRus  29-Seater  £299
4   Wheels  29-Seater  £290
5     Taxi  29-Seater  £300
```

Comment: Great Solution

How would one add the Filler Columns e.g. Mileage and any other Columns such as Fuel and Hours. As there will be multiple rows in the data set

Comment: Expand your initial question with the filler columns. Alternatively you can create a new question

Answer (score 1):

```
    import pandas as pd

# create the original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Mileage': [80],
    'Operator 1': ['BusRus'],
    '16.1-Seater': ['£199'],
    '29.1-Seater': ['£299'],
    'Operator 2': ['Wheels'],
    '16.2-Seater.1': ['£190'],
    '29.2-Seater.1': ['£290'],
    'Operator 3': ['Taxi'],
    '16.3-Seater.2': ['£200'],
    '29.3-Seater.2': ['£300']
})

# melt the dataframe from wide to long format
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Mileage', 'Operator 1', 'Operator 2', 'Operator 3'],
                  var_name='Seats', value_name='Price')

# split the 'Seats' column into two columns - one for the number of seats and one for the type of vehicle
df_melt[['NumSeats', 'VehicleType']] = df_melt['Seats'].str.split('-', expand=True)

# create a dictionary to map seat numbers to operator names
operator_map = {
    '16.1': 'Operator 1',
    '29.1': 'Operator 1',
    '16.2': 'Operator 2',
    '29.2': 'Operator 2',
    '16.3': 'Operator 3',
    '29.3': 'Operator 3'
}

# look up the correct operator based on the seat number and add it as a column
df_melt['Operator'] = df_melt.apply(lambda x: x[operator_map[x['NumSeats']]], axis=1)

# drop the original 'Seats' column and rename the remaining columns
df_melt = df_melt.drop('Seats', axis=1).rename(columns={'Operator 1': 'Dummy1', 'Operator 2': 'Dummy2', 'Operator 3': 'Dummy3'})

# drop the 'Dummy1', 'Dummy2', and 'Dummy3' columns and reorder the columns
df_melt = df_melt.drop(['Dummy1', 'Dummy2', 'Dummy3'], axis=1)[['Mileage', 'Operator', 'NumSeats', 'Price']]

# output the final dataframe
print(df_melt)
```

Not Ideal But I've found a work around by changing the Value of Seats for Each Operator. Seats.Operator_ID.

E.g.

```
# create a dictionary to map seat numbers to operator names
operator_map = {
    '16.1': 'Operator 1',
    '29.1': 'Operator 1',
    '16.2': 'Operator 2',
    '29.2': 'Operator 2',
    '16.3': 'Operator 3',
    '29.3': 'Operator 3'
}
```

Not The best Solution but will do. Hopefully it can help people in a similar problem. Although I'd be interested in better solutions.

I can strip the Decimals of the seats after